# Expo-go React-Native application that uses Google Authentication in Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, google-oauth

I am building a React-Native application with expo and test it with expo-go. I need to authenticate users to Firebase using Google.
I managed to authenticate users in Firebase with email+password, but not with Google.

I have spent several days looking for solutions on the web (and Stack-Overflow) and could not find anything definite or an example that actually works.
The proposed methods were: 'signInWithRedirect' and 'signInWithPopup' (both do not work in React-Native), 'expo-google-sign-in' (deprecated) and 'Expo-auth-session' (seems to be the latest method, but many claim it does not work with expo-go).

Is what I try to do even possible? is there a working example anywhere?

Otherwise, what would be the recommended way to authenticate users with Google in Firebase in my application (e.g., use builds instead of expo-go, or use Expo Dev Clients to enhance expo-go, etc.) - any working example please?

Many thanks in advance, I am getting desperate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a ridiculous amount of time on this (about a week) I finally gave up and moved to React-Native CLI instead of Expo.
In just a few hours, using the React-Native-Firebase package (that uses native code) I had no problems authenticating with Google.

(BTW - I tried to use React-Native-Firebase in a dev-client, but was not able to make it work)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get firebase google auth working through Expo Go using Expo SDK 47. With the release of Expo SDK 48 in February 2023, I believe it is no longer possible to get it working with Expo Go. See explanation of the SDK 48 updates [here](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-48-ccb8302e231).

I was reluctant to migrate to Expo Dev Clients, but it went smoother than anticipated, so I would recommend biting the bullet and moving forward with Expo Dev Client. I believe you will need a paid apple developer account to create the builds. The other issue I'm having with this method, is that I cannot seem to get the authentication flow working in a preview build, although it works fine in the development build. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76030003/google-login-working-in-development-build-but-not-preview-build) which has my code sample embedded, which works with the development build.

Comment: I solved my issue and now have it working in all builds. I had changed my project name at some point during development, so my expo project name no longer aligned with my bundle id. I created a new expo project with the new name, added my secrets to the expo project, re-configured the build, created a new "preview" build and voila! It works smoothly in both the dev build and the preview build.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party guys, but we've just spent about 2 days making it work. Check out our [blog post](https://scriptide.tech/blog/autheticate-to-firebase-with-google-oauth-login-with-expo-go-in-managed-expo-workflow-react-native-app) about it. It is definitely possible, even with Expo SDK 48. There is a link in the blog post to a git repo included where you can find a working example. Hope it helps some of you. :)

Update: The [Expo team says](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/24084) it's anti-pattern to use Expo Go for "longer than necesseray" - that includes Auth. However, for our use-case in development, it was perfectly okay.